# Save POST data to local server using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

Using nodeJs with express.

The POST data is being parsed by body parser. Now i want to save the received image file in a folder of express application named images. The image is being posted to nodeJs app. When i look at the res.body variable in the callback function it contains the image, but i am confused how to save it.

I have looked on stackflow but could not find any answer. So posted myself.

I have tried using the fs library and its fs.writeFile() function. It saves the file but it is all corrupted.

image1 is the name of image in posted data. Using bodyparser()

```
var image = req.body.image1;
        fs.writeFile('images/newImage.jpg', image, function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('It is saved');
        });
```

This saves a file in images directory but it is not the image.

I am using curl to post data to the nodejs application, the code is

```
$curl = curl_init();
$data = array('name' => 'First','file' => "image1=@".__dir__."/images/1.jpg");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:3000/api/");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I am logging both of the two console.log functions

```
   console.log(req.files);
   console.log(req.body);
```

and the log give

```
{}
{ name: 'First',
  file: 'image1=@C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\curltest/images/1.jpg' }
```

Please help this is driving me crazy :-/

Comment: @yeah sure! Edited the post for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the correct parameter order of [`fs.writeFile`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_encoding_callback) is the filename first then the content.

If you're using `express.bodyParser()` you'll have the uploaded files in the `req.files` field.

And of course you should write the callback:

```
fs.writeFile('newImage', req.files.image, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("It's saved");
});
```

#### Update

You should also check your HTML side, because the encoding of your form must be `multipart/form-data`.

Example:

```
<form action="/somewhere/to/post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image1"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Tried it, but it does not work, i have also edited the code in my post.

Comment: The uploaded files will be in the `req.files` field not in the body.

Comment: @but the console.log(req.files) always gives undefined

Comment: Are you using the bodyParser?

Comment: the multipart/form-data thing solved the issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Express 4, bodyParser is not included, 
but what you really need is to use a multiparty package, I use [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multiparty) and 
your code will be something like this:

within your POST router

```
var form = new multiparty.Form();

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send('not file');
        }
     res.send(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
});
```

hope this helps